# how can I use UINavigationController to switch between pages in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to swift development, I am trying to switch between UINavigation controller, I saw a snippet of code that performed this feature in Objective-c,

```
 UINavigationController* webViewNavigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:okraWebView];
      AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      ebViewNavigator.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
      [delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:webViewNavigator animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I am trying to replicate it for swift. how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 let webViewNavigator = UINavigationController(rootViewController: okraWebView)
 let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
 ebViewNavigator.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 delegate?.window.rootViewController?.present(webViewNavigator, animated: false)
```

Comment: I get the error `Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'`

Comment: @Oto-ObongEshiett
What is your app delegate class replace `AppDelegate` with you app delegate type

Comment: @Same7Farouk I am building a react-native bridge so an app delegate is not provided, but please is it possible to route without an AppDelegate?